# In material-table/core I want to display a list of data that is inside my rowData as detailPanel

Tags: reactjs, material-table

In my table each row has a list of attachments that I need to display in detailPanel.
This is my code of details panel

```
            detailPanel={(rowData) => {
              return rowData?.document_attachment ? rowData?.document_attachment.map((attachment) => {


                return <Box
                  sx={{ m: 1 }}
                  onClick={() => handleClickPreviewDoc(attachment)}
                >
                  <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "13px", display: "Flex", alignItems: "center", gap: "10px" }}
                  >
                    <FilePresentIcon sx={{ fontSize: "13px", opacity: "0.6" }} />
                    {attachment.name}
                  </Typography>
                </Box>
              }):<Box
              sx={{ m: 1 }}
            >
              <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "13px", display: "Flex", alignItems: "center", gap: "10px" }}
              >
                No Attachment Found
              </Typography>
            </Box>
            }}
```

This does not display any attachment even though it is inside the data.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is for someone who also had this problem, in order to access the list inside the rowData you have to write rowData.rowData.
so correct code is:

```
            detailPanel={(rowData) => {
              return rowData?.rowData?.document_attachment ? rowData?.rowData?.document_attachment.map((attachment) => {


                return <Box
                  sx={{ m: 1 }}
                  onClick={() => handleClickPreviewDoc(attachment)}
                >
                  <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "13px", display: "Flex", alignItems: "center", gap: "10px" }}
                  >
                    <FilePresentIcon sx={{ fontSize: "13px", opacity: "0.6" }} />
                    {attachment.name}
                  </Typography>
                </Box>
              }):<Box
              sx={{ m: 1 }}
            >
              <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "13px", display: "Flex", alignItems: "center", gap: "10px" }}
              >
                No Attachment Found
              </Typography>
            </Box>
            }}
```

This problem might only be in material-table/core.

Comment: you can also deconstruct it like detailPanel={( { rowData } ) =>{}. When using MUI datagrid it has the same thing. Just deconstruct the prop if you want to avoid typing things twice

Comment: @RyanZeelie yes, you are right.